# Minimizing quadratic form with quadratic and linear constraints

Tags: matrices, optimization, quadratic-forms, karush-kuhn-tucker, qcqp

I am trying to solve the following optimization problem

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}\\ \text{subject to} & \left(\mathbf{x}-m\mathbf{1}\right)^T \left(\mathbf{x}-m\mathbf{1}\right) \le a\\ & \mathbf{1}^T \mathbf{x} = b\end{array}$$

where

- $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is a symmetric, positive definite matrix.
- $\mathbf{1}$ denotes the vector of all ones.
- $a$, $b$ and $m$ are scalar positive values.

I have tried to apply KKT conditions but I am not able to find a closed-form solution. Is there any way to simplify this problem?

Comment: Using the Schur complement, you can rewrite the quadratic constraints as LMIs. Then, you are left with a (convex) semidefinite program.

Comment: Could you show me how?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2256241/339790). However, if you use something like CVX, you do not need to worry about such things. Assuming a numerical solution is fine.

Comment: I have already solved the problem with CVX. I was actually hoping to get some analytical results somehow but maybe it is not possible.