# Quadratic optimization problem with positive semidefiniteness constraint

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming

I have the optimization program

\begin{align}
\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n, Q \in \mathbb{S}^n} &\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\Vert x \Vert ^2 + b^T x\bigg)\\
\text{ subject to }&\text{tr}(Q \cdot A_1) + a_1^Tx = c_1,\\
&\text{tr}(Q \cdot A_2) + a_2^Tx = c_2,\\
&\qquad\qquad\vdots \\
&\text{tr}(Q \cdot A_m) + a_n^Tx = c_n.\\
&Q \succeq 0
\end{align}

Is there any way I can turn this into a primal semidefinite program?

As an attempt I have replaced the quadratic term in the objective with $\theta$ and then added the constraint $\frac{1}{2}\Vert x \Vert ^2 \leq \theta$. However I'm not sure how to deal with inequality constraints in an SDP. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2256241/339790).

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I've had a look at your post. However my problem also has a semidefinite constraint at the end.

Comment: Introduce optimization variable $y$ and try to transform the objective into an inequality that is LMI-representable.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Cheers - got it.

Comment: Just a slight warning: If your task simply is to solve this problem using some available solver, you would not rewrite the quadratic terms to semidefinite constraints, but write it using second-order cones if the solver supports that (most SDP solvers do). And if you use a modelling layer (which you should if you just want to solve it), you never do these reformulations at all, as the modelling language takes care of everything.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg I see, but how do I write the condition that the matrix is positive semidefinite as a quadratic inequality?

Comment: @Rishi You don't. Why would you do that?

Comment: To write it as a second order cone program wouldn't you need to have all constraints as a quadratic inequality? Of the form $\Vert Ax + b \Vert^2 \leq c^T x +d $

Comment: I'm talking about solvers supporting both semidefinite and second-order cones.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg Oh ok I got you. I'll have a look at that

Comment: What is your goal? If your goal is to obtain a numerical solution, then something like CVXPY can take your problem as it is and solve it. No need to rewrite in some delicate form.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo this is for a thesis - so more on the theory side. But I will have a look at these SDP solvers when I start to implement my model.

Comment: Note that $Q \succeq 0$ is a very succinct way of writing $2^n - 1$ inequality constraints. Only a few of those are quadratic.