# Maximizing/minimizing a quadratic form over an ellipsoid

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, qcqp

The goal is to solve the following maximization/minimization problem:

\begin{align*} &\max_y/\min_y y^TQy\\&\text{s.t.}(y-x)^\top V(y-x)\le\beta^2\end{align*}
where the optimization variable $y\in\mathbb R^{n}$ and the constant vector $x\in \mathbb R^n$. Matrices $Q\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ and $V\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$  are positive definite matrices. $\beta>0$ is a constant.

How to obtain the analytical expression of the optimal solution $y$ (non-trivally)?

It seems that the method in [Maximizing a linear function over an ellipsoid](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1832467) does not work well.

Comment: What do you mean by "the method [...] does not work well"?

Comment: The question "Maximizing a linear function over an ellipsoid" is solved by Lagrangian approach in the offered website.  The new question may not be solved by using Lagrangian approach.
\\
Website: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1832467/maximizing-a-linear-function-over-an-ellipsoid

Comment: Have you tried using the same approach? Now your objective is a strictly convex quadratic, which you can differentiate the same way the linear objective was differentiated on the other page.

Comment: Yes, if using the same approach, the Langrangian function can be rewritten as f(y)=y^TQy+\lambda[\beta^2-(y-x)^TV(y-x)]. Differentiating w.r.t. y, it follows that Qy+\lambdaV(x-y)=0, i.e. (Q-\lambda V)y=-\lambda Vx. The matrix (Q-\lambda V) may be a singular matrix. The value of y and \lambda may be not described by Langrangian approach.

Comment: I think $\lambda$ is negative (dual of an upper bound), so it's fine :)

Comment: Minimization is convex, but maximization is not.

Comment: The (convex) minimization problem can be rewritten as a semidefinite program (SDP). Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2256243/339790)

Comment: Negative $\lambda$ implies that $Q-\lambda V$ is positive definite. Then we can know that the optimal solution statisfies $y^*=-\lambda(Q-\lambda V)^{-1}Vx$ and nontrivally in the boundary of constraints, i.e. $(y^*-x)^TV(y^*-x)=\beta^2$. It is equivalent to $x^T[\lambda (Q-\lambda V)^{-1}V+I_m]^TV[\lambda (Q-\lambda V)^{-1}V+I_m]x=\beta^2$. This is why I say that $\lambda$ may be not described by Langrangian approach.  Thank you.【Reply to  cvanaret】

Comment: Thank you for the reference about the reformulation of the convex minimization problem by SDP. 【Reply to Rodrigo de Azevedo】

Comment: @OwnCandy You can now answer your own question for the minimization case.