# Transforming determining $\exists x \in \mathbb{R}^m, A(x) \succ 0$ into least squares possible?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, control-theory, semidefinite-programming, linear-matrix-inequality

Consider a linear operator $A: \mathbb{R}^{m} \to S^{n \times n}$, where $S^{n\times n}$ are the symmetric n by matrix.

> Can we turn the problem of determining if there exists $x \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ s.t. $A(x) \succ 0$ into a least square problem?

A least-squares problem is of the form

$$ \min_{y \in K} \|C(y) - b\|^2 $$

where we can determine the existence problem by checking if the optimal value is zero. K is a set, and C is another linear operator, and b is a column vector. We can formulate it in two ways, where $0$ either means existence or non-existence.

It is even better if we require K one set of positive semidefinite matrices. I don't care about the dimension.

---

Below are my thoughts, which are not necessary for the formulation of the problem

If we replace $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ by $S^{n \times n} \succeq 0$, the set of positive semidefinite matrices, I have come up a solution of doing this by solving the dual problem of separating the $\{ S \mid S \succ 0 \}$ and $\{ A(x) \mid x \succeq 0\}$. In this case, the two sets are separable iff exist such as x. I'm able to turn this into a least square problem but not the general case. Solving this existing problem is also known as an LMI Problem (LIMP).

Also, as I mentioned in the comments, I think this is just SDP. I am able to show that if it is feasible, then the least square is zero, but not the other way due to constraints qualification of the strong duality.

Comment: The motivation is that I have found an extremely fast way of solving particular kinds of least square problems. I wonder whether there are other ways of formulations though.

Comment: Isn't this a semidefinite program (SDP)?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thank you! I just realized this is just the dual program and it is strictly feasible, so I guess the primal can be turned into the least square form then by just setting b = 0?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Wait actually no, if I treat this existence problem as the dual problem, then the existence of x corresponds to the existence of the primal, which is least-square being zero, but the other way does not work. If the least square if zero, I would still need the primal to be strictly feasible for strong duality to hold. Unless there are other constraints qualifications.

Comment: SDP is optimizing a linear function over a spectrahedron.  LS is about the unconstrained minimization of a quadratic cost function. I am confused.

Comment: [Possibly related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2256241/339790)